# Reduce logical volume root

Tags: lvm

I have to reduce logical root volume of a pc, disk /dev/sda3.

can i do it starting with usb live system, ex Puppylinux? can i mount host's logical volume in Puppy linux?

thanks in advance

Comment: why would you meed to mount it? You can't resize it if it's mounted :p But yes, you should be able to manipulate it

Comment: What is the filesystem on this logical volume?

Comment: Q: why would you meed to mount it? You can't resize it if it's mounted :p But yes, you should be able to manipulate it
A: i wrong, excuse me...i mean "activate" lvm volumes

Q: What is the filesystem on this logical volume?
A: ext4


Howewer i have solved from Puppulinux with command: vgchange -ay

thanks to all